# how to delete characters placed next to cursor on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have recently shifted from PC to Mac and from what I recall on PC keyboards, there are keys where you can delete characters placed before your cursor as well as after cursor. I don't recall what the later is called.

I can't find something equivalent for Mac to delete post cursor characters.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For forward delete, hold down <kbd>fn</kbd> (the function key) and press delete.

Answer (score 2):

Laptop keyboards and Apple Wireless Keyboards use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete ⌫</kbd> for forward delete. Keyboards with a numeric keypad have a separate <kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> key like on other platforms.

Comment: Mac delete = backspace on other platforms, Mac forward delete = delete on other platforms.

Comment: If the topic starter is trying to "delete" something after the cursor, this is the way to do it.